# grep command to extract data from a file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file that has this line in it:

```
$n22(s:Tstring) =   "252";
```

I'm trying to write a shell command to grep the file and only return 252. 
This is what I have so far:

```
grep -o '$n22(s:Tstring).*;' /etc/test/testfile.cfg
$n22(s:Tstring) =   "252";
```

As you can see, it finds the line, but it returns everything.  I just want 252.  Can you tell me where I'm going wrong pls?

Thanks

Comment: You should read the documentation on grep, it is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be `grep`?  You could do it with `awk` like:

```
awk -F\" '/\$n22\(s:Tstring\)/ {print $2}'
```

with GNU grep at least you can use perl style regex and do it like so:

```
 grep -Po '\$n22\(s:Tstring\)[^"]+"\K[^"]+'
```

the `\K` means to not include everything that matched up to that point as part of the match for the `-o` option.